# Regular Expression to capture U+XXXX (or \uXXXX) characters in Java

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I've been trying to create PDF using PDFBox and it fails with errors like,

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: U+0083 is not available in this font's encoding: WinAnsiEncoding

I wanted to know if there is a way I could capture such elements using a Regular Expression, I've tried using,

```
(\\[a-z]00[0-9][0-9])
```

Which seems to work fine if I validate is using a RegexTool (like RegexBuddy) but doesn't work in Java! I've tried using Java Patterns and Matcher but no success. What I've done with Pattern Matcher is as follows,

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
public class MatcherFindStartEndExample {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String text    =
            "IMTECH Ã\u0083Â¢Ã\u0082Â\u0080Ã\u0093Â\u0083 " + 
            "ERCC Ã\u0099Â¢Ã PLANNED ";

    String patternString = "(\\[a-z]00[0-9][0-9])";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

    int count = 0;
    while(matcher.find()) {
        count++;
        System.out.println("found: " + count + " : "
                + matcher.start() + " - " + matcher.end());
    }
  }
}
```

The text I have right now appears something like,

> IMTECH Ã\u0083Â¢Ã\u0082Â\u0080Ã\u0093Â\u0083 ERCC Ã\u0099Â¢Ã PLANNED

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex will find all `backslash` + `u` + `4 digits`

```
String patternString = "[\\\\]+[u]+\\d{4}";
```

Output:

> found: 1 : 8 - 14
>
> found: 2 : 17 - 23
>
> found: 3 : 24 - 30
>
> found: 4 : 31 - 37
>
> found: 5 : 38 - 44
>
> found: 6 : 51 - 57

Answer (score 2):

I’m not sure exactly what you’re trying to do here, but `"\u0083"` is a [Java escape sequence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.3) representing *one* character, not six characters.  It will not be matched by the regular expression `"..0083"`, but it will be matched by `"."`.

Also, `"\\"` represents *one* character in a Java string, the backslash;  in a regular expression, that single backslash escapes the following character.  In your case `"\\["` matches a literal opening square bracket character.

But all of that may be irrelevant, since the presence of sequences like `Â¢` suggests you are mishandling UTF-8 data.  In particular, it looks like someone has forced every byte to a char value, instead of properly decoding the bytes using a [Charset](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html).  And then the same mistake was applied a second time to the new, incorrect String.

Working backwards, these characters:

```
ERCC Ã\u0099Â¢
```

correspond to these hexadecimal byte values:

```
45 52 43 43 20 c3 99 c2 a2
```

If, instead of forcing each byte value to be a char, you decode them as UTF-8 bytes, you get the string `"ERCC Ù¢"`.  If we again treat each char as a byte value, we get:

```
45 52 43 43 20 d9 a2
```

and if we once again decode those bytes using UTF-8, we get `"ERCC ٢"`, which I am guessing refers to [ERCC2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ERCC2).

If you fix the code which is extracting the text, you can match that string with something like `Pattern.compile("ERCC\\s*\\d+", Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS)`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you want to match for literally "\u0083", and not the unicode character that it represents.

Try `(\\\\u00[0-9][0-9])`.

Answer (score 0):

Your patternString searches literally for a text instead a character. 
You can search for a list of characters like this:

```
String patternString = "[\u0083|\u0082|\u0080]";
```

or for a list like this:

```
String patternString = "[\u0080-\u0090]";
```